# Joining two Spark DataFrame according to size of intersection of two array columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two `DataFrame` in my spark (v1.5.0) code:

```
aDF = [user_id : Int, user_purchases: array<int> ]
bDF = [user_id : Int, user_purchases: array<int> ]
```

What I want to do is to join these two dataframes, but I only need the lines where the intersection between `aDF.user_purchases` and `bDF.user_purchases` has more than 2 elements (intersection > 2).

Do I have to use RDD API or is it possible to use some function from org.apache.sql.functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any function built-in, but you can use UDF:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray;
val intersect = udf ((a : WrappedArray[Int], b : WrappedArray[Int]) => {
   var count = 0;
   a.foreach (x => {
       if (b.contains(x)) count = count + 1;
    });
    count;
});
// test data sets
val one = sc.parallelize(List(
        (1, Array(1, 2, 3)), 
        (2, Array(1,2 ,3, 4)), 
        (3, Array(1, 2,3)), 
        (4, Array(1,2))
        )).toDF("user", "arr");

val two = sc.parallelize(List(
        (1, Array(1, 2, 3)), 
        (2, Array(1,2 ,3, 4)), 
        (3, Array(1, 2, 3)), 
        (4, Array(1))
        )).toDF("user", "arr");

// usage
one.join(two, one("user") === two("user"))
    .select (one("user"), intersect(one("arr"), two("arr")).as("intersect"))
    .where(col("intersect") > 2).show

// version from comment
one.join(two)
    .select (one("user"), two("user"), intersect(one("arr"), two("arr")).as("intersect")).
    where('intersect > 2).show
```

Comment: You udf solution seems to solve my problem. Only one little note, I don't want to join on equal user ids, I want different user ids with at least three common elements in the array.

Comment: @Vektor88 so do cross join + filter after it. Will be quite slow, but there's no other option

Comment: Thank you very much, I've accepted your answer because the udf does what I want. Do you see any side effects in using the intersect > 2 as join condition instead of doing a filter later? I don't really need to have that value stored into a column

Comment: @Vektor88 you can try to run explain ;) But as far as I know, it would be rewritten to cross join + filter, but I don't have any Spark 1.5 installation currently to check it. There can be improvement in Spark 1.6 compared to Spark 1.5, so my `explain` results may be different

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to find interesting pairs and augment these with arrays. First let's import some functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
```

and rename columns:

```
val aDF_ = aDF.toDF("a_user_id", "a_user_purchases")
val bDF_ = bDF.toDF("b_user_id", "b_user_purchases")
```

Pairs matching the predicate can be identified as:

```
val filtered = aDF_.withColumn("purchase", explode($"a_user_purchases"))
  .join(bDF_.withColumn("purchase", explode($"b_user_purchases")), Seq("purchase"))
  .groupBy("a_user_id", "b_user_id")
  .count()
  .where($"count" > 2)
```

Finally filtered data can joined with the input datasets to obtain full result:

```
filtered.join(aDF_, Seq("a_user_id")).join(bDF_, Seq("b_user_id")).drop("count")
```

In Spark 2.4 or later you can also use built-in functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{size, array_intersect}

aDF_
  .crossJoin(bDF_)
  .where(size(
    array_intersect($"a_user_purchases", $"b_user_purchases"
  )) > 2)
```

although this might be still slower than a more targeted hash join.

Comment: Smart one :) But I think it can be quite slow, as physical plan is much bigger and contains few joins and sort